How to Set Up a Symbolic Link (Symlink) on Hostinger Shared Hosting
I'm trying to set up a symbolic link (symlink) on my Hostinger shared hosting account to link my public_html/storage directory to a folder located in storage/app/public. I attempted to create the symlink using the ln -s command, but I'm facing issues with the link either showing as "invalid" or not pointing to the correct target directory.
Here are the steps I followed:

Created the target directory using mkdir -p.
Ran the ln -s command to create the symbolic link.
Set permissions to 755 on the directories involved.
Despite this, the link either doesn't work or results in an "invalid link" error.

Can anyone guide me through the correct process for setting up a symlink on Hostinger shared hosting, or suggest possible causes for the invalid link issue? Are there any specific permissions or settings required for symlinks to work properly in this environment?
Any help would be appreciated!
i have tried all ls cmds but nothing worked and storage:link also didnt worked
ln -s /home/u789790412/domains/tomvpn.appapistec.xyz/storage/app/public /home/u789790412/domains/tomvpn.appapistec.xyz/public_html/storage

Same issue here. I don't think Hostinger allows that

Your best bet is either reaching out to the hostinger help (of which from my experience, they can't assist in this matter) or switching to a different hosting provider.

found that in hostinger shared hosting symlink is not available in it

I ran in to the same issue.
Symlink is disabled by default by Hostinger. --> Instruction image

yeah symlink only available on vps plans

@SameedEdiz No I got it to work using this method on my webhosting plan

I have created an answer for this problem and I hope it works for you guys. I am using Hostinger and purchased the premium one with the ssh access. I accessed my ssh to the main folder public html and run a similar code to this:
ln -s /home/u789790412/domains/tomvpn.appapistec.xyz/storage/app/public /home/u789790412/domains/tomvpn.appapistec.xyz/public_html/public

Now, do exactly as mentioned:

Go to public_html/public folder and there you will see a public-> link folder like that. Rename that into storage.

Then the links will now work.


The renaming is the trick I used because when I am developing it on my local device, I am using asset('storage/...'), that's why I have adjust it and renamed the folder to storage.
I am uploading files and the link works fine because I think, the link also adjust when I had run the location link.
I hope this will help you.
